# Internal server error when Deploying Zend Framework in cPanel

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, cpanel, chmod

I just deployed my Zend project in a hosting service. I upload my project as archive then extracted in public_html folder. so I have this directory:

> public_hmtl 
>   ->application (folder) 
>   ->libary (folder)
>   ->public (folder)
>   ->test (folder)
>   ->cgi-bin (folder) (this not belong to me in the first place) 
>   ->buildpath
>   ->htaccess (this not belong to me in the first place) 
>   ->project
>   ->zfproject.xml
>   ->index.php (this is for redirecting to /public)

When I run the site, it shows :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@myweb.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I did the project in localhost using xampp and it works fine. But when I uploaded in cPanel, it became like that.

I have set the chmod for folder to 755 and file to 644. I think it has to do with the htaccess but I don't quite understand how  to deal with that in cPanel.

What should I do?

The error log shows something like this:

```
[Sat Sep 10 15:10:39 2011] [error] [client 125.163.228.77] File does not exist: /home/publicusername/public_html/404.shtml
[Sat Sep 10 15:10:39 2011] [error] [client 125.163.228.77] File does not exist: /home/publicusername/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sat Sep 10 15:10:39 2011] [error] [client 125.163.228.77] File does not exist: /home/publicusername/public_html/500.shtml
[Sat Sep 10 15:10:39 2011] [alert] [client 125.163.228.77] /home/publicusername/public_html/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'SetEnv', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
[Sat Sep 10 15:09:58 2011] [error] [client 125.163.228.77] File does not exist: /home/publicusername/public_html/404.shtml
```

my public/htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I have set the `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV` to `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production` in public/htaccess, but still failed.

Comment: Did you check the error log? What does it say?

Comment: first please copy .htaccess file here. second check error log in cpnale

Comment: SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]                                     i have edited the question with the eror log

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to point to `SetEnv`. My best guess is your host is using a *really* old version of Apache (pre 1.3.7) or has not enabled `mod_env`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is not right folder structure. Folder 'public_html' should not contain all project tree, here should be only 'public' folder contents. Other folders (application, library, test etc.) should be outside 'public_html' folder. 'Public_html' is your web-root directory. You may imagine 'public_html' as alias of your 'public' folder.

That folders structure I use in my current project (Server is on CentOS and CPanel is used). May be you will have a problem if name 'public' is used in source. In this case you might to define alias in the main 'index.php' file and use it in other places.

Comment: Whilst not ideal, the OP's folder structure is not a cause for error.